# How to use/expose vivus.js methods in react

Tags: reactjs, vivus

I'm using react component for vivus.js library, but don't know how to use its Methods, e.g. I would like to call myVivus.play() on slide change, but not sure how. I'm just learning react, as I understand I need to expose component's methods to use it in render, but so far all my attempts were unsuccessful. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactVivus from 'react-vivus';
import ReactFullpage from '@fullpage/react-fullpage'
import Svg1 from './example.svg';
import Svg2 from './example2.svg';


const Anim1 = () => (
  <ReactVivus
    id="anim1"
    option={{
      file: Svg1,
      animTimingFunction: 'EASE',
      type: 'oneByOne',
      onReady: console.log
    }}
    callback={console.log}
  />
);

const Anim2 = () => (
  <ReactVivus
    id="anim1"
    option={{
      file: Svg2,
      animTimingFunction: 'EASE',
      type: 'oneByOne',
      onReady: console.log
    }}
    callback={console.log}
  />
);


const FullpageWrapper = fullpageProps => (
  <div>
  <SEO title="Home" />
  <Menu>
    <MenuContainer>Logo</MenuContainer>
  </Menu>
  <ReactFullpage
    {...fullpageProps}

    //fullpage options
    licenseKey = {'***'}
    navigation
    anchors={['intro', 'reasonOne', 'reasonTwo']}
    sectionsColor={['#4e5c9e', '#d3d7f2', '#F5F5F6']}

    render={({ state, fullpageApi }) => {


      return (
        <div id="fullpage-wrapper">
          <div className="section section1 light">
            <SlideWrapper>
              <TextBlock>
                <SlideHeader>Header 1</SlideHeader>
                <SlideDescription>Description text 1</SlideDescription>
              </TextBlock>

              <AnimationBlock>
                <Anim1/>
                <button onClick={() => this.play()} >Play</button>
              </AnimationBlock>
            </SlideWrapper>
          </div>

          <div className="section section2">
            <SlideWrapper>

              <AnimationBlock>
               <Anim2/>
              </AnimationBlock>

              <TextBlock>
                <SlideHeader>Header 2</SlideHeader>
                <SlideDescription>>Description text 2</SlideDescription>
              </TextBlock>

            </SlideWrapper>
          </div>

          ...


        </div>

      );
    }}
  />

  </div>

);


export default FullpageWrapper;
```

Comment: you want to trigger the animation programmatically via a button but the component animates itself without user action, right ?

Comment: @EmmanuelMericdeBellefon I'm using FullPage.js library to create one page sections, each section have vivus.js animation. On scroll/section change I want to trigger animation (play it again). Right now it only plays once on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the thing is that react-vivus is a small wrapper arround vivus.js, but is not really complete.
The creator of the library didn't let any way to call the methods from vivus.js such as `play` that you want to call. He let himself an issue about this [here](https://github.com/HelloQingGuo/react-vivus/issues/1) by the way.

That said, what you want can be done with a bit of tricky code, like this :

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import ReactVivus from 'react-vivus';
import svg from './example.svg';

const MyVivus = () => (
  <ReactVivus
    id="foo"
    option={{
      file: svg,
      animTimingFunction: 'EASE',
      type: 'oneByOne',
      onReady: console.log
    }}
    style={{ height: '100px', width: '100px' }}
    callback={console.log}
  />
);

function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true)

  const handleReset = () => {
    setShow(false) // unmounting here
    setInterval(() => setShow(true), 0) // re-mounting a fraction of second later
  } 

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {show ? <MyVivus/> : null}
      <button onClick={handleReset}>reset</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

What happens is that we remove the component and we put it back in very fast, so that the animation triggers again.

To integrate it in your code :

```
const FullpageWrapper = fullpageProps => {
  const [shown, setShown] = useState(true)

  const handlePlay = () => {
    setShown(false)
    setInterval(() => setShown(true), 0)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <SEO title="Home" />
      <Menu>
        <MenuContainer>Logo</MenuContainer>
      </Menu>
      <ReactFullpage
        {...fullpageProps}
        licenseKey = {'***'}
        navigation
        anchors={['intro', 'reasonOne', 'reasonTwo']}
        sectionsColor={['#4e5c9e', '#d3d7f2', '#F5F5F6']}
        render={({ state, fullpageApi }) => (
          <div id="fullpage-wrapper">
            <div className="section section1 light">
              <SlideWrapper>
                <TextBlock>
                  <SlideHeader>Header 1</SlideHeader>
                  <SlideDescription>Description text 1</SlideDescription>
                </TextBlock>
                <AnimationBlock>
                  {shown ? <Anim1/> : null}
                  <button onClick={handlePlay}>Play</button>
                </AnimationBlock>
              </SlideWrapper>
            </div>
            <div className="section section2">
              <SlideWrapper>
                <AnimationBlock>
                  <Anim2/>
                </AnimationBlock>
                <TextBlock>
                <SlideHeader>Header 2</SlideHeader>
                <SlideDescription>>Description text 2</SlideDescription>
              </TextBlock>
            </SlideWrapper>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    />
  </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! However, when I try to call the App() function inside render I get the following error:
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: App is a component too ! it's just here to demonstrate. You would instantiate it like ```<App/>```.

Comment: Just consider it is ```FullpageWrapper``` from your question.

Comment: Ah, you are right! It shows the "reset" link now and restarts animation on click. But is there a way to call that function on fullPage state change? Here's how I can trigger console.log function for example on fullPage state:
`render={({ state, fullpageApi }) => {
      console.log("render prop change", state);`

Comment: Ok, so render function shouldn't perform state update. Looking at the library there's a prop for ```<ReactFullpage>``` called ```onLeave``` which takes a callback as parameter. So it would be ```onLeave={handlePlay}``` on ```<ReactFullPage>```.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your help!